# Hibernate criteria to fetch Data from 3 table's + Sum of a Specific Column and also group by a column name.

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to use Hibernate criteria to fetch Data from 3 table's + Sum of a Specific Column and also  group by a column name.

Table 1 
Table 2 
Table 3

1.) Select Some of the Columns in table 1, table 2, table 3
2.) sum of a Particular column 
3.) Group By on a specific column

It will be helpful if I can write Criteria for this.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote down the criteria myself,

List result = session.createCriteria(Table1.class)

```
.createAlias("Table2", "Tb2")
.createAlias("Table3", "Tb3")
.add( Restrictions.eqProperty("Tb2.someColumn", "some Property from Model") )
 .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
     .add( Projections.avg("someproperty") )
    .add( Projections.max("someproperty") )
    .add( Projections.groupProperty("someproperty") )
)
.list();
```

Felt like it will be useful to others like me...